# How to have "Copy To (My app)" on a UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, uidocumentinteraction

[image: Copy To]

How can I have a "Copy To MyExampleApp" in a UIDocumentationController.
The file types can be any : pdf,pptx,doc,txt ...

P.S : Objective-C code will be helpful. 
Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding DocType Support to your App for the extension and then handle the delegates to do the needful.

Reference: [Registering the filetypes your app supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [fileURLFromLaunch path];
BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:finalFilePath error:&error];
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"success");
}}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. Please try to understand the question.

Comment: @OmkarJadhav I thought u have config the that in Application Info.plist file, This is actual code u have to write after copy clicked